# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-sass

I am getting this error after upgrading rails from 5.2 to 6.1.0 and ruby from 2.5 to 3.0.2. It was working fine for ruby 2.7 and rails 6.0 version.

It was working fine on bootstrap-email version 0.3.0 but it will break after upgrading 1.0.1 with ruby 3.0.2.

I have also raised same issue on GitHub, here is the link
https://github.com/bootstrap-email/bootstrap-email/discussions/143

```
mailer/changed_password_alert
  should verify reset password email content (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) mailer/changed_password_alert should verify reset password email content
     Failure/Error: @import 'bootstrap-email';

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-email.
               on line 6:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/mailer/index.scss
       >> @import 'bootstrap-email';

          ^
     # ./app/assets/stylesheets/mailer/index.scss:6
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:50:in `render'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails/template.rb:40:in `block in call'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:138:in `module_include'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails/template.rb:39:in `call'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:27:in `call'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:119:in `[]'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:358:in `find_asset'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:337:in `digest_path'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:326:in `asset_path'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:103:in `block in resolve_asset_path'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:243:in `block in resolve_asset'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `each'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `detect'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `resolve_asset'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:102:in `resolve_asset_path'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:80:in `compute_asset_path'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:186:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:184:in `map'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:184:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
     # ./app/views/mailer/changed_password_alert.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_mailer_changed_password_alert_html_erb__553806408343225745_26440'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/haml-5.2.2/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:15:in `render'
     # ./spec/views/mailer/changed_password_alert.html.erb_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:80:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/strategy.rb:30:in `cleaning'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/cleaners.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/cleaners.rb:35:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/vishal_pandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/webmock-3.14.0/lib/webmock/rspec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # SassC::SyntaxError:
     #   Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-email.
     #           on line 6:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/mailer/index.scss
     #   >> @import 'bootstrap-email';
     #
     #      ^
     #   ./app/assets/stylesheets/mailer/index.scss:6

Top 1 slowest examples (0.19216 seconds, 20.0% of total time):
  mailer/changed_password_alert should verify reset password email content
    0.19216 seconds ./spec/views/mailer/changed_password_alert.html.erb_spec.rb:6

Finished in 0.9595 seconds (files took 22.39 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

System configuration

```
Rails version: 6.1.0
Ruby version:  3.0.2
bootstrap-email version: 1.0.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try installing premailer-rails gem. bootstrap-email requires it.

https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails